# How to display my logo in panel wrapper instead of actual position in Magento 2.3?

Tags: magento2

I want to display my logo in **panel wrapper** instead of actual position in Magento 2.3.
How can I do that?
Something like

[image]

instead of

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find which header style your are using and edit your header style in 
app\design\frontend\\market\Magento_Theme\templates\html\header-style.

Add your custom html in that file.

```
  echo $block->getChildHtml('logo_theme');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can move **logo** to **header.panel.wrapper** using your theme's **default.xml** file.

Open  **app\design\frontend\Vendor\Themename\Magento_Theme\layout\default.xml** file add below code:

```
<move element="logo" destination="header.panel.wrapper" before="-"/>
```

This will move logo inside "panel wrapper" class.